# How to build completely new data type of size n in C or C++ without using any of the user defined data type?

Tags: c++, c, types

Say for int the data size is by default 4 bytes for double its 8 bytes. can we built such a datatype of size n say 64 bytes or 100 bytes. i do not want to make use of the internal datatype or any user defined data type.
Presently working on a project which requires high data manipulation capabilities. working with long double but the program halts when the data value gets increased from 20-25 digits.

Comment: it should be in C or C++

Comment: You should use long arithmetics instead.

Comment: i am already using long double

Comment: User defined data types and internal data types are the only data types there are. So if you don't want to use either, your life as a C++ programmer is going to be pretty miserable.

Comment: seems like making my path miserable is the only choice i have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot "build" a new native type, not without (of course) patching the compiler to extend the language. At that point you're no longer working in standard C (nor C++), but some extension thereof.

The point of C and C++'s native types is to express a decent approximation of what typical CPU hardware can do, at a native level. You can't expect to "go beyond" that in terms of types without expecting to do the work, i.e. implement the abstraction.

Multiple-precision libraries work by representing larger numbers using many native numbers, and including code to do the arithmetic as needed. This is well-established practice, and there are many mature such libraries around, such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

It it was possible to just "build a datatype" to go around this problem, those libraries would not exist.

Comment: Nice, +1 for providing an example, this is what the OP probably needs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, I edited to make that somewhat clearer.

Comment: can u list some more like GMP!